# do_release_upgrade: GUI doesn't start

Tags: do-release-upgrade

I did a do_release_upgrade on my Ubuntu 16.04 (there were errors, in particular some were related to X11 or Xorg) and now I have this at boot:

[image]

Help !

**EDIT** I reinstalled grub from a live Ubuntu and now I have this at boot, still need help!
[image]

BOOT INFO is here http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HKwrjh7R4d/

BOOT REPAIR report is here http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jHwQNZ8Ryv/

`lsb_release -a` gives `18.04 Bionic` .

`$ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -i "VGA"` gives

```
VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
Subsystem: Lenovi HD Graphics 5500
kernel driver in use i915
```

then:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**EDIT 2** I have access to command line via tty1, I tried to reinstall xserver `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg` but it still boots on the black screen with [ OK ] lines as in the screeshot above.

**EDIT 3** I tried reinstalling GDM

```
sudo apt purge gdm gdm3
sudo apt install gdm3 ubuntu-desktop
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3 #to choose GDM
systemctl restart gdm
```

I also tried `startx` and I get:

```
X.Org X Server 1.19.6
...
using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set OIPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
xinit: connection to server lost
waiting for X server to shut down. (II) server terminated sucessfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Comment: mmm yes and no, I reinstalled grub as recommended in the other thread with sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/  /dev/sda, a bit better but still not booting...I'm editing the question. I remember I had some X issue..display wise....anyway I can reinstall X ?

Comment: I tried a few things with Xorg but in vain. Can you help ?

Comment: Do a fresh install. This happens.

Comment: no I don't want to do a fresh install. I would have done it already.